# What is the problem or What's wrong with this code (Uri 1049 question)?

Tags: c, uri

this code compiles successfully but after getting the first input, it terminates.

I tried to solve this for several hours but couldn't find the actual problem.

Does this problem occurring for strcmp command? i am trying to solve **uri 1049** no problem and i wrote this but it isn't working. the problem link https://www.urionlinejudge.com.br/judge/en/problems/view/1049

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{

char input[10],      
first1[10]="vertebrado",
first2[10]="invertebrado",
seco1[10]="ave",
seco2[10]="mamifero",
seco3[10]="inesto", 
seco4[10]="anelideo",
thi1[10]="carnivoro",
thi2[10]="onivoro",
thi3[10]="onivoro",
thi4[10]="herbivoro",
thi5[10]="hematofago",
thi6[10]="herbivoro",
thi7[10]="hematofago",
thi8[10]="onivoro";
scanf("%s",&input);

if(strcmp(input,first1)==0)
{
  scanf("%s",&input);

  if(strcmp(seco1,input)==0)
  {
     scanf("%s",&thi1);
     if(strcmp(input,thi1))
     {
        printf("aguia");
     }
     else if(strcmp(input,thi2)==0)
     {
       printf("pomba");
     }

     }
       else if(strcmp(seco2,input)==0)
     {
        scanf("%s",input);

        if(strcmp(input,thi3)==0)
        {
           printf("homem");
        }
        else if(strcmp(input,thi4)==0)
        {
           printf("vaca");
        }
      }
   }
   else if(strcmp(input,first2)==0)
   {
     scanf("%s",&input);
     if(strcmp(input,seco3)==0)
     {
        scanf("%s",&input);

        if(strcmp(input,thi5)==0)
        {
            printf("pulga");
        }
        else if(strcmp(input,thi6)==0)
        {
             printf("lagarta");
        }

       }
       else if(strcmp(input,seco4)==0)
       {
          scanf("%s",&input);
          if(strcmp(input,thi7)==0)
          {
             printf("sanguessuga");
          }
          else if(strcmp(input,thi8)==0)
          {
             printf("minhoca");
          }
        }

      }
}
```

Comment: `thi7[10]="hematofago"` - this will give you undefined behavior right away when you try to use it. It is too short to contain this string including null-terminator.

Comment: Thanks a lot and it works now